# Doubt in proof of Rolle's Theorem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, limits, derivatives

While Proving Rolle's Theorem we have if $M$ and $m$ are Supremum and Infimum values of $f(x)$ in $\left[a ,\:\: b\right]$ and $M \ne m$

Then Supposing $f(a) \ne M$, Then $f(b) \ne M$ and Now there exists $c \in (a, b)$ such that $$f(c)=M$$

Now in the Neighborhood of $c$ there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that

$$f(c+\epsilon)< f(c)$$ $\implies$

$$f'(c)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(c+\epsilon)-f(c)}{\epsilon} \lt 0 \tag{1}$$ Similarly

in the Neighborhood of $c$ there exists $\epsilon \gt 0$ such that

$$f(c-\epsilon)< f(c)$$ $\implies$

$$f'(c)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(c)-f(c-\epsilon)}{\epsilon} \gt 0 \tag{2}$$

Now since $(1)$ and $(2)$ are contradicting we have

$$f'(c)=0$$

Now my Doubt is in my book, there is also equal to sign in both $(1)$ and $(2)$

How can there be equal to sign?

Comment: what book is this?

Comment: Limits preserbe *large* inequalities, not *strict* inequalities. Example: $\frac1n >0$, but $\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac1n =0$.

Answer (score 3):

I don't quite understand your question, but I believe the confusion lies in the following. The correct version of $(1)$ is
$$f'(c)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(c+\epsilon)-f(c)}{\epsilon} \leq 0,$$
and the correct version of $(2)$ is
$$f'(c)=\lim_{\epsilon \to 0}\frac{f(c+\epsilon)-f(c)}{\epsilon} \geq 0.$$

For a computational example to witness this firsthand, you might check out $f(x) = -(x-1)^2 + 1$ on $[0, 2]$. Sometimes working out an example clears up any remaining confusions.

Comment: Or the example $f(x)=-x^2$ on $[-1,1]$, with $c=0$..............+1